# JavaScript API Domain is restricted to localhost phonegap

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I am trying to get linked in authentication on my phonegap app so I am using the javascript sdk

What domain do I add to the authentication list? I keep getting the error "JavaScript API Domain is restricted to localhost"

and I tried this: http://www.benwagner.net/mobile/linkedin-developer-api-javascript-domains-cordova-mobile-app/

But linkedin won't allow file:/// anymore

Comment: Is the application working in desktop browser ?

Comment: Yes but no sign in @11thdimension

Comment: I mean is the sign in working in the browser with `http://localhost` ?

Comment: No unfortunately :( @11thdimension

Comment: What are you trying to do? What is the purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see that there seems to be no way to support mobile application Java Script API domain. As the mobile application has no public domain but just a socket, it's a client.

As the link that you have provided claimed to have found a solution in 2013 by just mentioning the protocol `file:///` in the domain. However I found another link from 2014 which says that this doesn't work anymore. May be you can try adding `file:///, http://localhost`.

This should in effect (if the `file:///` is allowed) should allow your application on mobile and in localhost browser to sign in.